# How to "avoid" changes in children are visible in parent

Tags: angular, typescript, binding

This is the scenario. In my application with angular 8 i have a grid with products. Every row has some info like name of the product, date of creation, etc.

When i double click one row, a modal shows up showing the details of the selected product and i can edit them.

Then I can do 2 things. I can save the changes or just cancel and hide the modal.

When i just cancel and the modal hides, **i can see all the changes i did in the modal reflected in the respective row of the products grid**. How can I avoid that? I know that its how immutability works, and I already tried the option of

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy
```

in `@Component` declaration changing the property to `onPush` but it was a disaster and it broke everything (Even i read about this, I don't know how exactly works neither)

Shall i clone the [input] of the child component? What is the workaround for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChangeDetectionStrategy only determines when the UI will be updated. So that does not help in your case.

If you are using model binding with [(ngModel)] to your input fields, I suggest to clone your object before passing it to the modal. If you click save replace the old one with new one. If you click cancel just throw the clone away.

Comment: Oh, ok so I was mixing different concepts... I expected angular 8 introduced something to avoid that. Seems like i am forced to clone the object. Thanks man!